# QuerySet with Avg

Tags: django, django-queryset, average

I'm having problems making a queryset for a report :/

The ChangeLog model (please see model picture below) stores every change in MedicalRequest model. I'm trying to get the time average from first record to last record in ChangeLog for a single MedicalRequest. I'm querying from customer because I'need make some reports.

[image: Database models]

I already test this:

```py
customer = Customer.objects.get(pk=10)
customer.medicalrequest_set.aggregate(avg=Avg(Max(changelog__timestamp),
  Min(changelog__timestamp)))
```

but I'm getting 'changelog__timestamp' is not defined :( 
any idea?

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with your syntax. `changelog__timestamp` is treated as a variable, which you haven't defined. You have to pass the name as a string to these functions. Like, `Max('changelog__timestamp')`.